# How do you change the text color of a disabled component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can change the background color using a custom class but not the text color which remains grey.

```html
<v-list-tile slot="activator" class="static" :class="{'disable-events':disabled}" :disabled="item.disabled">
    <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-tile-title>
    <v-list-tile-action class="justify-end">
        <v-icon>play_arrow</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
</v-list-tile>

.disable-events {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to make it so that when you click the `Source` and `Results` menu-item, the context menu doesn't close, so I disabled the components, and am trying to make the colors the same as their default.

Comment: using 'color' also doesn't work, the font is still grey

Comment: You have a typo:it's rgba not rbga

Comment: Good catch, unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The css attribute you want is ‘color’, not ‘fontColor’

Comment: Still have the same problem

Comment: Use the element inspector in your browser. It’ll give you the color that’s applied, and then what CSS element is seeing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes is that fontColor doesn't exist. Use color instead

```
.disable-events {
     color: your color;
}
```

Comment: Still have the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Remember the semicolon, I see you edited the ask without them. It would work. If it doesn't, the background is changing? Maybe the css class is not being added correctly